# Flags Enum attribute

Tags: c#, enums, flags

What is the point of the [Flags] attribute you can bit test without it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Flags attribute allows you to see a CSV(comma separated value) of your enumerated type when calling `ToString()`

For Example:

```
[Flags]
public Enum Permissions
{
  None =0,
  Read = 1,
  Write =2,
  Delete= 4
}

Permissions p = Permissions.Read | Permissions.Write;
p.ToString() //Prints out "Read, Write"
```

However you can still get the same thing if you remove the flags attribute and just do:

```
p.ToString("F") //Prints out "Read, Write"
```

And as John pointed out it also allows you convert a CSV back to Enum using `Enum.Parse`

Answer (score 5):

It changes the behaviour of converting between strings and the enum values (`Enum.Parse` and `ToString`).

Comment: Offtopic, but I just noticed you are the first one to cross 200 000 reputation. Congrats:)